# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable while finding longest common subsequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to find the longest common subsequence among two strings
.So far I have written following code

```
def LCS(u, v):  # u[0..m-1], v[0..n-1]
      for r in range(len(u) + 1):
        LCS[r][len(v) + 1] = 0  # r for row
    for c in range(len(v) + 1):
        LCS[len(u) + 1][c] = 0  # c for col
    for c in range(len(v), -1, -1):
        for r in range(len(u), -1, -1):
          if (u[r] == v[c]):
            LCS[r][c] = 1 + LCS[r + 1][c + 1]
          else:
            LCS[r][c] = max(LCS[r + 1][c],
                    LCS[r][c + 1])
    print (LCS[0][0])
s = input()
si=input()
LCS(s,si)
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/udit/PycharmProjects/untitled/l.py", line 16, in <module>
    LCS(s,si)
  File "C:/Users/udit/PycharmProjects/untitled/l.py", line 3, in LCS
    LCS[r][len(v) + 1] = 0  # r for row
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? If you intend to call the function `LCS` then it's recursion gone mad.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is named `LCS`.  You can't subscript a function object.

What is the purpose of (for example) this line of code:

```
LCS[r][len(v) + 1] = 0  # r for row
```

Are you intending to recursively call the LCS function?  If so, you have two issues.

First, to call a function, you need parentheses.  Something like this:

```
LCS(foo, bar)
```

But you clearly know this already, because LCS is called correctly at the bottom of the code example.  So I'm not sure what to think.

Assuming that you were intending to call LCS, the second larger issue is that you're assigning to the *result* of the function, and that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: How does this explain anything as an answer? The issues are so broad... And this just re-states the error

Comment: @roganjosh I have expanded upon my answer.